# upgrading Ubuntu 18.04 to Debian/Unstable (amd64) on Dell 7920 workstation

Tags: debian, ubuntu

I just got a brand new (high-end) desktop workstation at work. It is a [Dell Precision 7920](http://www.dell.com/si/business/p/precision-7920-workstation/pd) workstation (with some Intel 10 cores processor, probably Xeon Silver 4114, 128Gb RAM, 500Gb SSD, 1Tb hard-disk, some Nvidia graphics, perhaps NVIDIA Quadro P2000 - I forgot the details). The only Internet connection I can use is thru the Ethernet on that desktop. And I don't want to bother colleagues by asking to use their Internet and workstation, even to browse the web. It is replacing some old i7 desktop machine which was almost 8 years old (forgot the brand, perhaps a lenovo) and which was running debian/unstable (updated nearly daily).

I am quite familiar with Debian/Unstable, and using it at work -on a previous PC that is no more available- (and at home) since many years.

The main Ethernet controller is (IIRC) some Intel i210 (and i219 for the secondary, or viceversa). And I cannot switch (even temporarily) to the (unused) secondary Ethernet controller, because my physical MAC address is known to the corporate network (and not the second one), DHCP, IPv4 with NAT.

A debian/testing ISO image is able to boot, but does not recognize the Ethernet controller (something wrong with the `igp` or `e1000` kernel modules, perhaps some `incr_refcount` kernel routine missing). AFAIU debian/testing is the required step to go to debian/unstable (there is no debian/unstable ISO image).

An Ubuntu 18.04 amd64 desktop ISO image is able to boot and recognize the Ethernet controller, so I installed it (at least temporarily) but I really prefer Debian/Unstable.

I'm thinking of **changing all the entries in `/etc/apt/sources.list` from Ubuntu to Debian/Unstable** (e.g. by restoring them from the backup of `/etc/` on the previous computer). Then running `aptitude update` and `aptitude full-upgrade`. I am afraid of using `debootstrap` on the root partition of my system.

**Should that work** for most of the system (I could manage not having Xorg working temporarily, but I need the Ethernet; it is the *only* Internet connection at work that I can use without disturbing colleagues) **??**

Otherwise, how to change the kernel of some Debian/Testing image? Or how to build a Debian/Testing ISO with a modified kernel? (or build a Debian/Unstable ISO with a modified kernel (one on which the network works); [this](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Modify/CustomKernel) seems obsolete)

PS. I'm posting from home, and did not write on paper all the details (e.g. the output of `lspci` or the error messages) of my brand new work desktop.

### addenda

Actually, my Debian Testing iso (weeksly snapshot) image was buggy, and that is a known bug [#903047](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=903047). Will try next week to boot [debian buster](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/buster_di_alpha3/amd64/iso-cd/) di alpha3

Comment: Nice idea - but unfortunately that won't work. If you want to replace Ubuntu with Debian, you have to perform a clean installation of the Debian system. This is the answer - but I thought I'd provide it as a comment ... :)

Comment: Any other suggestion? E.g. how to change the kernel of some Debian/Testing iso image?

Comment: No Basile, unfortunately not - everything else would be nothing more than just kind of "wishful thinking" ... :)

Answer (score 4):

It's very much not avdisable (even if it is theoretically *maybe* possible) to "upgrade" (sidegrade? slantgrade?) from one distribution to another.  Let's take one very simple example looking at trying to go from Ubuntu to Debian:

```
$ apt show apt # edited for brevity
Package: apt
Version: 1.2.27
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: APT Development Team <deity@lists.debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Depends: [...] ubuntu-keyring, [...]
```

...Oh.  Okay, so `apt` depends on `ubuntu-keyring`.  So I can't uninstall that without removing `apt` first.  Which means I'll no longer have `apt` to install or uninstall anything.

If you're changing distributions, you will have a much better time of it (and probably spend a lot *less* actual time) simply backing up your data and doing a fresh installation of your newly-chosen distribution.

Comment: But how do you suggest solving the network driver issue?

Comment: Outside the scope of the underlying question, but: if you identify a Debian package that will work, obtain the `.dpkg` for it _and_ any of its dependencies you might need.  Install Debian.  Copy the packages to disk.  Use `apt` or `dpkg` to install them.

Answer (score 1):

The way I'd approach this is as follows. It involves running Ubuntu and Debian simultaneously as VM Host and Guest with different parts of the same physical disk. Provided the two running systems do not attempt to write to each other's disk partitions this will work. However, it's not for the faint-hearted...

1. Allocate a small-ish (say 15GB) partition for installing the Ubuntu distribution you know works. If you're really keen, allocate it at the end of the disk. Install Ubuntu into it. Shared root and boot. No swap.
2. Fire up KVM with your real disk as its guest disk (yes really).
3. As a guest inside the KVM install your Debian/Unstable onto the remainder of the disk. Keep the initial installation as small and simple as possible (no "task" selections at all, for example). You can extend it later. Use the Ubuntu system to provide your virtualised networking needs (NAT or Bridge; it doesn't really matter). My personal preference is to use LVM for as much as possible so that I don't need to assign disk sizes too early (15GB for root, 10GB for home, 1GB for swap, etc.) Use physical disk drivers rather than virtualised ones even though KVM may warn you it's not as efficient. You may want a separate `/boot` partition. **DO NOT TOUCH the Ubuntu partition!** Allow `grub` to update the boot partition but not if it thinks it's still part of the Ubuntu system.
4. Ensure that the necessary physical ethernet modules have been installed within your Debian/Unstable and then shutdown the VM
5. Reboot from Ubuntu into the newly installed Debian/Unstable, this time as the physical machine rather than as a VM guest. You may need to fix-up some of the disk partition names (`/dev/vdaN` or `/dev/sdbN` might need to be rewritten as `/dev/sdaN`, etc). If you were able to use disk UUIDs you will probably be fine.
6. If you find you're missing parts of the Debian/Unstable, reboot back into Ubuntu and fire up Debian/Unstable as a VM guest once more.
7. Once you've got networking sorted properly in your Debian/Unstable OS (i.e. as a physical OS rather than as a virtualised guest), install the remainder of the system to suit - graphics, productivity tools, etc.
8. When you're sure everything is working as expected you can delete the Ubuntu partition and extend the previous partition into the now-empty disk space.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I am not familiar with KVM (and I dislike the idea of using it). However, I might try something similar, using `debootstrap` and `chroot` (I believe a Debian distro should run under an Ubuntu kernel in chroot). I can afford having a 150Gb partition for Debian's root filesystem

Comment: BTW, I don't have any NAT on my machine. The NAT is in the corporate network (my desktop is just a DHCP client with an IP which is practically fixed by the network). My employer [CEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Alternative_Energies_and_Atomic_Energy_Commission) is a large organization (more than 10K computers on site), somehow the French equivalent of DoE in the USA

Comment: That comment about NAT or Bridge refers to the networking within the KVM subsystem. If you use NAT the guest is effectively invisible to the rest of your corporate network. (Its actions are attributed to your main machine.)

Comment: Also, are there reasons which would invalidate a similar approach, but using `chroot` & `debootstrap` in a separate partition? Unless the Ubuntu kernel cannot work with a Debian root (I did not try, but I guess it is very likely to work) I don't see any reason

Comment: Sorry, I've no idea, but it does sound like a good idea